# Radio button not working with jquery repeater

Tags: jquery, html, jquery.repeater

[image: Repeater field]I've the following code for repeater field. All the input fields in the repeater field except the radio button are working.

```
<div data-repeater-item>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <div class="custom-radio">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="period_type" id="inlineRadio7" value="Month">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio7">Month</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <div class="custom-radio">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="period_type" id="inlineRadio8" value="Day">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio8">Day</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="period" placeholder="00">
            <label class="form-check-label">Month</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="form-check-label">Default price
                <!--per Month--></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="default_price" placeholder="00,000">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="form-check-label">Discounted price
                <!--per Month--></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="discount_price" placeholder="00,000">
        </li>
        <li class="add-remove">
            <input class="remove" data-repeater-delete type="button" value="- Remove" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When clicking the radio button of 2nd or the following radio buttons group, the first radio button group is changing (Because of the id that i've provided for the radio input i think ). How to make the radio buttons works too?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check 2nd-row `id` & `labelfor` val

Comment: Each repeater row should have **unique** `ID`, label `for="ID"` & `name` then month-day ratio button will work.

Comment: yes, jquery repeater automatically set unique name for name attributes (by using array formats), but i'm not sure how to deal with the id issue

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: https://codepen.io/apurba_jnu/pen/yaxpRa  - Check this url there is well define everything which you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every row unique `ID`, `lablefor` & `name` `val`

```
    <div class="repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="category-group">
        <div data-repeater-item>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="cat-id" />
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <div class="custom-radio">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="period_type" id="inlineRadio7" value="Month">
                                Month
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <div class="custom-radio">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="period_type" id="inlineRadio8" value="Day">
                                Day
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="period" placeholder="00">
                    <label class="form-check-label">Month</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        Default price
                        <!--per Month-->
                    </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="default_price" placeholder="00,000">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        Discounted price
                        <!--per Month-->
                    </label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="discount_price" placeholder="00,000">
                </li>
                <li class="add-remove">
                    <input class="remove" data-repeater-delete type="button" value="- Remove" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" />
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                'use strict';
                window.id = 0;

                $('.repeater').repeater(
                    {
                        defaultValues: {
                            'id': window.id,

                        },
                        show: function () {
                            $(this).slideDown();
                            console.log($(this).find('input')[1]);
                            $('#cat-id').val(window.id);
                        },
                        hide: function (deleteElement) {
                            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
                                window.id--;
                                $('#cat-id').val(window.id);
                                $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                                console.log($('.repeater').repeaterVal());
                            }
                        },
                        ready: function (setIndexes) {
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
```

Use Custom Radio with bootstrap HTML

```
<label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-label">Or toggle this other custom radio</span>
</label>
<label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-label">Toggle this custom radio</span>
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/034tp2ar/7/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm using jquery repeater which dynamically add each rows, so i have no control over setting each repeater field of radio buttons a diifferent id.And also i've only one div of <div data-repeater-item>

Comment: Thanks, this answer seems working using default radio button, but i'm using custom radio buttons (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-1 ) something like this. Is there any workaround for this too?

Comment: I have added custom radio button HTML with boostrap

Answer (score 0):

You have given same name to radio buttons hence they work as a single group and hence whenever you click on one of them other will get de-selected.

You need to give different names to the radio button in different row to work independently

```
<!--- First row -->
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <div class="custom-radio">
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
                  name="period_type_7" id="inlineRadio7" value="Month">
           <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio7">Month</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
         <div class="custom-radio">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
                   name="period_type_7" id="inlineRadio8" value="Day">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio8">Day</label>
         </div>
    </div>

   <!--- Second row -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <div class="custom-radio">
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
                  name="period_type_9" id="inlineRadio9" value="Month">
           <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio9">Month</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
         <div class="custom-radio">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
                   name="period_type_9" id="inlineRadio10" value="Day">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio10">Day</label>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't mind the first option (Month) getting unchecked, when we click on day, But the issue is when clicking the 2nd row of this radio buttons repeater, only the initial buttons (First row) are getting chnaged

Comment: In that case, keep same name for radio button in same row but follow different name for different row

Answer (score 0):

You may use jquery to replicate Items and get them using class index like:

```
var repeater = doucument.getElementsByClassName('class-name');
```

And get using

```
repeater[index];
```

I have tested the code in the following link: 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Form-Fields-Repeater.html

Comment: Sorry, can you please describe repeater[index]; , Where should i use this?

Comment: This is only for demo purpose in case you need to get the value of selected radio button use index of the elements. As a matter of fact getElementsByClassName gets all the radio buttons with a classname.